Point Release build JS Bundle to localhost
I have a vision for IDE-free development. We build a special flavor of a release build on CI. CI takes care of all the tricky xcode and android bits. And then our user can just modify the JS code while connected to a release build and never needs to touch android studio or xcode or local dependencies outside of JS.
So, how can I point a release build to the localhost js bundle?

Isn’t this expo?

@johnhaup Yeah, expo does something similar. I'm in a production environment that can't fully buy into expo's suite so we can't rely on them unfortunately. But they do prove it's possible.

It’s deploying a js bundle. You can look at what codepush does and copy that.

Hmm I guess codepush does push bundled js bundles to deployed apps. I was thinking something more geared towards live development though with all the perks that come from having a running js bundle that will refresh on code changes etc.
